# AngularJS table in demo mode recalling dummy data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, jquery-pagination

So I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EnY74/20/ that is recalling some kind of demo data

As you can see in this example https://jsfiddle.net/vsfsugkg/2/ the table only has one row and I modified that row to just contain (1, 2, 3).

The table still has 1,222 entries so it must be recalling demo data in the javascript.

How can I stop the table from using the dummy data and use this example on my site? I have already wrapped it around a table in my site but the table is doing that same thing repeating 1,222 times.

```
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('PaginationApp', []);

App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'TypekitService', '$filter', function($scope, Typekit, $filter){
$scope.loadData = function(){                         Typekit.getTypekits($scope.page, $scope.per_page).then(function(response){                    
        $scope.more = response.data.library.families.length === $scope.per_page;
        $scope.families = $scope.families.concat(response.data.library.families);
        $scope.status_bar = "Showing " + ($scope.families.length === 0 ? "0" : "1") + " to " + $filter('number')($scope.families.length) + " of " + $filter('number')(response.data.library.pagination.count) + " entries";

    });
};

$scope.show_more = function(){
    $scope.page += 1;
    $scope.loadData();
}

$scope.has_more = function(){
    return $scope.more;
}

$scope.per_page = 10;
$scope.page = 1;        
$scope.families = [];        
$scope.more = true;
$scope.status_bar = "";
$scope.loadData();    
}])


App.factory('TypekitService',['$http',function($http){
return {
    getTypekits : function(page, per_page){
        return $http.jsonp('https://typekit.com/api/v1/json/libraries/full?page='+page+'&per_page='+per_page+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    }
}
}]);
```

When I apply this pagination to my website table I get each row repeated 20 times so I end up with an initial display of 200 rows with an option to load more, does anyone know why? The table in question only holds no more than 20 records?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what you're trying to do but what happens is this.

1. the call to `Typekit.getTypekits` gets the remote data (1,222
   records).
2. The retrieved data is assigned to scope variable 'families'.
3. In the HTML template you are iterating over all entries of array 'families'.
4. Since the template over which you are iterating only contains 1,2,3, the result is a table with 1,222 rows containing 1,2,3.

If you just want to show one record. Remove the call to getTypeKits and initiate the families array yourself.

I updated the example removing all unnecessary stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/vsfsugkg/18/

Comment: I want the pagination only your jsfiddle doesn't have pagination?

Comment: I just want to be able to wrap this around any foreach php table on my website and have it paginate the data

Comment: Okay, I brought the pagination back ;-)
https://jsfiddle.net/vsfsugkg/18/

Instead of doing the XHR (ajax) call, we're using dummy data. The example now has three 'pages' of data. Hope this helps. If like this answer please upvote or accept my answer :-)